Thermodynamic quantities during free expansion and joule Thomson expansion
What happens to thermodynamic quantities like internal energy, heat, work done and entropy during free expansion and joule Thomson expansion of both ideal and real gases. I always find this very confusing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to know what thermodynamic quantities remain constant, change (in the sense increase or decrease).

For both real and ideal gases entropy is generated (entropy increases) and internal energy stays the same as the result of free expansion. Entropy increases because more micro states become available due to the greater volume.
As it is highly improbable that the gas would spontaneously return to its original side of the container, the expansion is irreversible. An external influence by the surroundings would be needed to return the system to its original state (original entropy). That would increase the entropy of the surroundings.
Internal energy remains the same because no energy in the form of work or heat is transferred between the gas and its surroundings owing to the fact that the container of the gas is both rigid and insulated.
The difference between the real and ideal gas is the difference between the final and initial temperature.
For an ideal gas the temperature remains the same because the internal energy is considered purely kinetic as it assumes there are no intermolecular interactions that can cause a change in internal molecular potential energy of the gas when it expands.
For most real gases there will be a decrease in temperature, i.e., a decrease in the average molecular kinetic energy. This is due to the fact that there will be in increase in the molecular potential energy resulting from the separation of the gas molecules. However, the decrease in internal molecular kinetic energy equals the increase in molecular potential energy for a total change in internal molecular energy of zero.
Hope this helps

I will add quantitative details to Bob D's answer.
Joule expansion
There is no work or heat exchange $W=Q=0$ so to internal energy variation $\Delta U=0$ and volume $V$ varies. For a gas, you only have two degrees of freedom, so this is enough to specify the initial and final state. All variations of quantities can be deduced from the equations of state for equilibrium. To relate this to known quantities, you can imagine small increments of volume $dV$ in which case, any thermodynamic variable $X$ changes according to:
$$
dX = \left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial V}\right)_UdV
$$
You typically have three variables of interest: $S,T,P$. For entropy, you get:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_U = \frac PT
$$
so entropy increases with volume.
For temperature, the case of ideal gases is special: $\Delta T=0$. In general, a real gas will change temperature according to:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_U &= \frac{P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V}{T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V} \\
&= \frac{P\kappa_T-T\alpha}{C_V\kappa_T}
\end{align}
$$
The sign depends on the numerator, with the temperature inversion point where it perfectly cancels at:
$$
T\alpha = P\kappa_T
$$
Joule Tompson expansion
It is essentially the same idea. This time there is no change in enthalpy $\Delta H = 0$ and pressure $P$ varies because there is no heat $Q=0$ and no work $W'=0$ (apart from pressure). Similarly, entropy decreases:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_H = -\frac VT
$$
Again, for ideal gases $\Delta T=0$, but for real gases, the general variation is:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)_H &= -\frac{V+T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P}{T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P} \\
&= V\frac{T\alpha-1}{C_P}
\end{align}
$$
The sign depends on the numerator, with the temperature inversion point where it perfectly cancels at:
$$
T\alpha = 1
$$
